# d3 chart legend overlapping

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Can someone help me identify why my these specific legends overlap each other?

This is my code for constructing the legends and the spacing

```
  lSpace = WIDTH / dataGroup.length; 
vis.append("text")
.attr("x", (lSpace / 2) + i * lSpace)
.attr("y", HEIGHT)
.style("fill", function() { // Add the colours dynamically
  return d.color = color(d.key);
})
.attr("class", "legend")
.on('click', function() {
  var active = d.active ? false : true,
    opacity = active ? 0 : 1;
  // Hide or show the elements based on the ID
  d3.select("#tag" + d.key.replace(/[ )(]/g, ''))
    .style("opacity", opacity);
  // Update whether or not the elements are active
  d.active = active;
})
.text(d.key);
```

I've been playing around with this to get the legend to space it accordingly no matter how many data legends there are. Unfortunately no matter how I space the legends I get one that overlaps the other.

Here is a fiddle: 
https://jsfiddle.net/9gzcbajx

Comment: You are not taking the width of text into consideration. You need to wrap the text. [Here's](http://d3-legend.susielu.com/#size-line) nice library to make legends

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I personally always prefer to wrap legends into `g` component, and translate it based it's content size .

That way is more space saving & readable

key code is this

```
var startX = 30;

legends.each(function(d, i, arr) {
  var wrapper = d3.select(this);  //this is g
  var text = wrapper.select('text');
  var bbox = text.node().getBBox();
  wrapper.attr('transform', 'translate(' + startX + ')');
  startX += bbox.width + 35;
})
```

I have updated your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uxLze316/1/)

Please be aware, that I have decoupled legends drawing from loop

Comment: How can we break the lines of text instead of adjusting x positions for this case ?

Comment: I have gone through this link.Is that (wrap) work for legend text as well ?

Comment: As long as it's only text, does not matter if it will be a legend, axis or another visualization element

Comment: Still if I add more labels to the legend those labels are not showing in the legend. Is there a way to accommodate any number of legend strings. https://jsfiddle.net/yasirunilan/zu0v64t3/1/